# How to merge two rows in R

Tags: r, csv, event-log

Below is a table that I have in R. (event log)

```
Case.ID | Activity | Timestamp |    Resource   |   State
------------------------------------------------------------
   0    |Take order| 00:12:04  |     Waiter    |   Assign
------------------------------------------------------------
   0    |Take order| 00:18:02  |               |  Complete
------------------------------------------------------------
   1    |Bring food| 00:47:23  |  Cook helper  |   Assign
------------------------------------------------------------
   1    |Bring food| 00:52:41  |               |  Complete
------------------------------------------------------------
   1    |Bring food| 00:54:52  | Cook helper   |   Assign
------------------------------------------------------------
   1    |Bring food| 00:59:11  |               |  Complete
```

Rows with value in the column Resource is a start of the activity and end of the activity has no value in that cell.

I tried,

```
assign <- subset(csv, select=c(Case.ID,Activity,Timestamp,State), State=="assign")
complete <- subset(csv, select=c(Case.ID,Activity,Timestamp,State), State=="complete")
merge <- merge(assign, complete, by=c("Case.ID", "Activity"))
```

but it shows some error like below.

Second and fourth rows should be eliminated but not sure the way to do it.

```
Case.ID | Activity | Start.Timestamp | End.Timestamp |
------------------------------------------------------
   1    |Bring food|    00:47:23     |    00:52:41   |
------------------------------------------------------
   1    |Bring food|    00:47:23     |    00:59:11   | 
------------------------------------------------------
   1    |Bring food|    00:54:52     |    00:52:41   |
------------------------------------------------------
   1    |Bring food|    00:54:52     |    00:59:11   |
```

Comment: Is your output correct?

Comment: if you need to get rid of duplicate rows, you can use `df <-
 dplyr::distinct(df)` or `df <- unique(df[, 1:4])`, assuming your data frame only has those four columns

Comment: I edited to write the exact code that I typed in.

Comment: @Craig Sorry, there was a typo. I fixed it. It is not about the problem of duplicate rows.

Comment: Where did activity `Take Order` go? You only have `Bring Food`... also I m almost off work and I m hungry :)

Comment: @Sotos There was no problem with the activity `Take Order` so I just skipped it. lol grab some food.

Answer (score 0):

Create an extra grouping variable and then reshape to wide format like this:

```
df$grp <- cumsum(df$Resource!='')

library(reshape2)
df2 <- dcast(df, Case.ID + Activity + grp ~ State, value.var = 'Timestamp')[,-3]
```

which gives:

```
> df2
  Case.ID   Activity   assign complete
1       0 Take order 00:12:04 00:18:02
2       1 Bring food 00:47:23 00:52:41
3       1 Bring food 00:54:52 00:59:11
```

An alternative with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
df2 <- dcast(setDT(df)[, grp := cumsum(Resource!='')], 
             Case.ID + Activity + grp ~ State, value.var = 'Timestamp')[, grp := NULL][]
```